# Floating point subtraction issue in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point

This is a very simple issue to duplicate. I am doing a simple subtraction using floating point numbers.  As you can see from the code below and the corresponding output, the calculation is not correct.

(php 5.6.6 on OSX El Capitan)

```
<?php

    $bal = 20017.1;
    $amt = 20000;
    $newbal = $bal - $amt;

    print_r(compact('bal', 'amt', 'newbal'));
    echo "\n";
```

As you can see from this output, $newbal is not correct.

```
Array
(
    [bal] => 20017.1
    [amt] => 20000
    [newbal] => 17.099999999999
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an explanation of why this is happening, see here:

http://floating-point-gui.de/

If you know in advance the precision you need, one simple solution is to use the [`bcsub()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcsub.php) method:

```
$bal = 20017.1;
$amt = 20000;
$newbal = bcsub($bal,$amt,1); // 17.1
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/PZ4qS

Answer (score 0):

You need to use functions to get accurate results with floating point numbers in PHP.  Try using https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php specifically the bcsub function, and explicitly tell it how many decimal places of accuracy you want.